# Numpy finding rows in array that correspond to values in another array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have the following arrays:

```
arr1 = np.array(['x','y','z'])

arr2 = np.array(['y','a','b','z','c','x'])

arr3 = np.array([['y','d1','d2','d3'],
                 ['a','d4','d5','d6'],
                 ['b','d7','d8','d9'],
                 ['z','d10','d11','d12'],
                 ['c','d13','d14','d15'],
                 ['x','d16','d17','d18']])
```

and I want to get the following:

```
answer = np.array([[x,d16,d17,d18],
                   [y,d1,d2,d3]
                   [z,d10,d11,d12]])
```

How do I do this??

Comment: Could you name your arrays differently? I think `x, y` and  `z` are already been used for the inner values of your matrices.

Comment: Sorry about that, has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, or at least get you in the right direction.

```
idxs = np.where( arr3[:,0] == arr1 )
answer = arr3[idxs, :]
```

read about np.where: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: I get the idea, but I think it does not work, because  `==` is not made for comparing different shaped arrays in a way `where` makes use of. In short: Not working for my example...

Answer (score 0):

```
inds = [ where( arr3[:,0] == val)[0] for val in arr1 ]
inds = [ i[0] for i in inds if i.size ] 
answer = arr3[inds]
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the first row (`next()`), where the first element equals an element `e1` of `arr1`.

```
array([
    next(row3 for row3 in arr3 if row3[0]==e1)
      for e1 in arr1])
```

Out:

```
array([['x', 'd16', 'd17', 'd18'],
       ['y', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3'],
       ['z', 'd10', 'd11', 'd12']], 
  dtype='|S3')
```

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) has functionality to address this problem efficiently. You can think of it as a vectorized equivalent of list.index. Should be in numpy itself if you ask me; maybe in a future version!

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
answer = arr3[npi.indices(arr3[:,0], arr1)]
```